# ECMAS6 arrrow function and classical function scope

Tags: javascript

I'm digging into EMCA6 and I would like to know if this:

```
var fruits= [10,20,30];
this.iterator = 1; 
var result = fruits.map(function(nrb) {
       return nbr + this.iterator;
}.bind(this));
```

is equivalent to :

```
var fruits= [10,20,30];
this.iterator = 1;
var result = fruits.map( nbr => nbr + this.iterator);
```

For me this is exactly the same thing but I was wondering if I was missing something. Any trap ?

Comment: Yes it is for your purposes. But you really should not use `this` in a global scope - I hope that was only for this example.

Comment: lets say I'm in the global scope, what is the difference of scope between fruits and iterator then ?

Comment: One is a property, the other is a variable. Just use two variables - and give them some local scope if possible.